# Use calendar to display anniversary

Tags: views, datetime

I've a site that collects historical events.
I would to use calendar to display a block with events of actual the months (that, obviously, could be events in every year, also in XIX century).
How should I set the contextual filter to do this?

Generically I need a calendar of anniversary..

Thanks,
Sergej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module can be used to set up recurring events. An event on a specific date can occur multiple times. There's a basic tutorial at http://www.bentedder.com/recurring-calendar-setup-in-drupal-7/