# Calendar - "It happened today" type

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a database of persons with birth/death times (Year-Month-day) and biographical data, and I want to make a Calendar View that lists the birth/death events that happened on some specifical day. Eg. a person born 1845. Dec. 16. would show up in this calendar at the field Dec. 16 - With name and biographical data. Also, the viewer could list back in time for other months, to see what happened on dates from eg. August, May, April etc.

I tried to make a calendar with the content types and filters, but had no luck.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: See this: https://www.drupal.org/node/320584 sadly, Birthday does not integrate with views.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use calendar to display anniversary](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31957/use-calendar-to-display-anniversary)

Comment: The anniversary display did help me, Thanks! 
But for some reason, I can only set one recurring date per custom post type (although I did set it up for unlimited - I need at least two). Any clue why?